# How to download a file from website by submitting the form without browser

Tags: forms, file, download

how can i download a file from specific website, by accepting agreements: http://www.freedrweb.com/download+cureit/?nc=t&lng=en

I wanna do this without browser, better some solution on server side (in linux) level...

Comment: You can use wget or Curl

Comment: Maybe you have some code snippets to solve my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you don't even have to submit a form, just take the URL of the .exe you want and then :

```
wget http://download.geo.drweb.com/pub/drweb/cureit/cureit.exe
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. But exist some feature to work with form parameters? :)

Comment: Well yes, you have to look in the man page for wget option, I don't know then. If you are using PHP, you can use Curl either. With both you can make a request to an URL an pass POST parameters.